# std::typeid() donot throw bad_typeid exception while derefencing the NULL pointer

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

Exception is only raised for class NULL pointers.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Test
{
    public:
    Test(){}
    virtual ~Test(){}
};
int main()
{
    Test *ptrvar = nullptr;
    char* cptr = nullptr;
    try 
    {
        cout << typeid(*cptr).name() << endl;
        cout << typeid(*ptrvar).name() << endl;
    }
    catch (bad_typeid) 
    {
        cout << "The object is null" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
c
The object is null
```

Can somebody explain to me why typeid() does not raise the bad_typeid exception for dereferencing char NULL pointer?

Comment: You missed the begging where is required that *expression* identifies an object of a polymorphic type... `char* cptr` does not point to a polymorphic type, `*cptr` identifies `char`. `Test* ptrvar` points to a polymorphic type, the operator does not know `*ptrvar`'s actual type from `nullptr` (that may be some child) thus raises the exception.

Comment: `typeid` is a keyword, not a member of `std` namespace. `std::typeid` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 3):

[expr.typeid]/3:

> When `typeid` is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a polymorphic class type, the result refers to a `std​::​type_­info` object representing the static type of the expression. Lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, and function-to-pointer conversions are not applied to the expression. If the expression is a prvalue, the temporary materialization conversion is applied. **The expression is an unevaluated operand.**

[emphasis added]

So, when the operand is a `char *`, the typeid depends solely on its being a `char *`, and the expression (the dereferenced null pointer) is not evaluated.

Since `*ptrvar` is a glvalue of (potentially) polymorphic class type, its operand is evaluated.

In this case, the compiler could apply an optimization: since no class derived from `Test` has been compiled, it could deduce that `ptrvar` can only point to an object of type `Test`, not anything derived from `Test`--but while that's pretty easy in this case, it can be non-trivial (or impossible) in other cases, so it's not required.